# titan manyToOne missing from 0.4.4 -> 0.5.4

Tags: cassandra, titan, gremlin

I am upgrading titan from 0.4.4 to 0.5.4.

Per http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.5.4/upgrade.html, schema creation has big change in 0.5.4. So I use getManagementSystem and replace makeKey with makePropertyKey and most of our schema creation script is working except:

In 0.4.4, we have g.makeLabel('site1').manyToOne().make(). In 0.5.4, makeEdgeLabel doesn't have manyToOne method, how can I specify manyToOne in 0.5.4 then?

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the `multiplicity` constraint on edge labels.

http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.5.4/schema.html#_edge_label_multiplicity

```
mgmt = g.getManagementSystem()
follow = mgmt.makeEdgeLabel('follow').multiplicity(Multiplicity.MULTI).make()
mother = mgmt.makeEdgeLabel('mother').multiplicity(Multiplicity.MANY2ONE).make()
mgmt.commit()
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion. I need to revisit schema doc again.:-) Cheers!